# Done button action from IQKeyboardManager not working in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

We are using `IQKeyboardManager` library for Swift project. Its working fine, but, After clicking the "Done" button its not calling the method.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myTextField.delegate = self
        self.myTextField.keyboardToolbar.doneBarButton.setTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked))
}

 @objc func doneButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        //your code when clicked on done

    }
```

And the library version is

> pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '6.0.2'

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'r code it's work :/ ,  you can use  `textFieldDidEndEditing`

Comment: please add IQKeyboardManager version

Comment: Updated the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is issue in `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` version `6.0.2`

[Fixed issue](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/commit/1f65aa001001b7448379a3bdf309ab209964dae0)

You can use `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
   func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        print("done click ")
 }
```

or update  `IQKeyboardManagerSwift 6.0.3`

> pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '6.0.3'

Answer (score 0):

```
// Don't set button for keyboardToolbar. Set button direct to textfield.
    self.myTextField.doneBarButton.setTarget(self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonClicked(_:)))
```

Comment: Not helped with this.